# Reversing list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm Trying to write function with using reverse function.
I want to simply reverse list NOT like

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]  
reverse' [] = []  
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

but like 
rev [a] = reverse[a]

When I use reverse function in haskell

```
Prelude>[1,2,3]
[3,2,1]
```

When I'm trying to use:

```
Prelude>rev [1,2,3]
```

I got:
*** Exception: 2ost.hs:1:1-20: Non-exhaustive patterns in function rev

Please help , I'm assuming that It's some stupid mistake.

Ok I know :
[a] was taken by haskell as 1 element list, solution is:

```
rev a = reverse a
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want a shorter alias for the `reverse` function. Any time you want an alias in Haskell, you can create it very easily - just do something like `rev = reverse`.